# Using xamarin to access Wordpress wp job manager jobs

Tags: wordpress, xamarin, xamarin.forms, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to access job data from my wordpress website where I am using the WP Job Manager plugin. I am using xamarin forms with WordPressPCL (https://github.com/wp-net/WordPressPCL) where I am able to use the api to get all posts/comments/pages etc... but I can't seem to find a way to be able to get the Job Listings data. I have tried to find the table in phpMyAdmin but it isn't there so I can't access the data that way.

I installed the WP REST API plugin on my site as well and can't see the information I am looking for when I navigate to siteurl/wp-json/wp/v2/

Json Data Paths:

[image: Json Data Paths]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might be able to get a list of all Jobs in the Job Listings toolbar that can be viewed in the admin panel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That addin provides a custom `wpjm/v1` endpoint that is a work in progress and disabled by default (`WPJM_REST_API_ENABLED`) and would not be included via the std WP endpoint. You might want to look the code (https://github.com/Automattic/WP-Job-Manager/blob/08db0c863f5bfa90a272b0a36352f36fc9c177b0/includes/rest-api/class-wp-job-manager-rest-api.php)

Comment: @SushiHangover Awesome, thanks for the reply. I looked into your suggestions and was able to enable the endpoint. But unfortunately wpjm/v1 doesn't include the job listing items which I assume are not yet enabled seeing how it is still being developed.